# Reporting against a column in my data extension? - Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, custom-report-type

I'm looking to create a report based on a column in my sendable Data Extension used in a deployment in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Ideally, I would like the report to look similar to "Email Performance by Attribute" which is based on a list model.

Is there a sample query I can reference to target a specific column in my data extension to retrieve tracking details of a deployment that was sent out?

Comment: Can you provide more info on exactly what you mean? Like do you mean you want to get sent/open/click count based on unique values in a column? e.g. column Group has values 'A,B,C' in it and you want to find out the tracking info based on those in Group A, Group B and Group C.  e.g. `Group A | 34 | 10 | 2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Like do you mean you want to get sent/open/click count based on unique values in a column?
 
Exactly!

I would like a breakdown based on the standard metrics of the send "sent/open/clicks etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from optimized, but its something that I have used in the past for a similar need:

```
Select a.myGroupField,
MAX(sen.Sent) as Sent,
MAX(ope.Opens) as Opens,
MAX(uope.UniqueOpens) as UniqueOpens,
MAX(cli.Clicks) as Clicks,
MAX(ucli.UniqueClicks) as UniqueClicks
FROM [myDE] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.myGroupField,
    COUNT(se.SubscriberKey) as Sent
    FROM [myDE] b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT s.SubscriberKey
        FROM [_Sent] s
        WHERE s.JobID = 123456
    ) se
    ON b.SubscriberKey = se.SubscriberKey
    GROUP BY b.myGroupField
) sen
ON a.myGroupField = sen.myGroupField
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.myGroupField,
    COUNT(op.SubscriberKey) as Opens
    FROM [myDE] b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT o.SubscriberKey
        FROM [_Open] o
        WHERE o.JobID = 123456
    ) op
    ON b.SubscriberKey = op.SubscriberKey
    GROUP BY b.myGroupField
) ope
ON a.myGroupField = ope.myGroupField
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.myGroupField,
    COUNT(uop.SubscriberKey) as UniqueOpens
    FROM [myDE] b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT uo.SubscriberKey
        FROM [_Open] uo
        WHERE uo.JobID = 123456
        AND uo.IsUnique = 1
    ) uop
    ON b.SubscriberKey = uop.SubscriberKey
    GROUP BY b.myGroupField
) uope
ON a.myGroupField = uope.myGroupField
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.myGroupField,
    COUNT(cl.SubscriberKey) as Clicks
    FROM [myDE] b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT c.SubscriberKey
        FROM [_Click] c
        WHERE c.JobID = 123456
    ) cl
    ON b.SubscriberKey = cl.SubscriberKey
    GROUP BY b.myGroupField
) cli
ON a.myGroupField = cli.myGroupField
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.myGroupField,
    COUNT(ucl.SubscriberKey) as UniqueClicks
    FROM [myDE] b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT uc.SubscriberKey
        FROM [_Click] uc
        WHERE uc.JobID = 123456
        AND uc.IsUnique = 1
    ) ucl
    ON b.SubscriberKey = ucl.SubscriberKey
    GROUP BY b.myGroupField
) ucli
ON a.myGroupField = ucli.myGroupField
GROUP BY a.myGroupField
```

Do note that this query is fairly heavy and if you are looking at a significant volume in your sending audience, it may time out. If so, you can break the query into multiple parts and run each individually to fill in the target DE.